# JBPM: how to get and restart all stored StafeulKnowlegeSessions that were stored before a system crash?

Tags: java, jboss, persistence, jbpm

I would like to recover the state of my stateful knowledge sessions after there was a system crash. Is there any API method to do so? If not, is any way to get all the available sessionIds, so I can load them with `JPAKnowledgeService.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `JPAKnowledgeService`, the returned `StatefulKnowledgeSession` (either by loading or creating) is already persisted and is always updated when any state change occurs.
So you just need to load the same session you were using prior to the crash, by passing the same id to `JPAKnowledgeService.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession`.

Although no API options exist to retrieve the ids of the sessions you are using, you can either manage those ids yourself, or make a direct (and I must say ugly) query using the same datasource that is used by the `JPAKnowledgeService`.